# Nuxt 3 + WP REST API + Pinia + local.storage, is a good method per user login?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, middleware, nuxtjs3, pinia

The application I'm developing includes NUXT 3 for the frontend and Wordpress for the backend. The data is passed from the backend to the frontend using the REST API.
The application is a sort of CMS, in this way all the routes are protected by a middleware that makes sure the user is logged correctly. The middleware checks if the localstorage exist or not, because it's created when the user is able to log in.

In order:

1. For each route the middleware checks if the localstorage userAuthentication exists, if it doesn't exist you are redirected to /login. This middleware run globally, but only in client side.
2. When the user try to enter in the application, a POST call is made to the WP backend with the credentials filled by him. If the endpoint returns CODE 200, the data are saved in the PINIA store and then a localstorage will be created with the data of the response (including the token). At this point the user can navigate in all the protected routes.
3. When the user log out the localstoraged is destroyed, then he will be redirect to /login.

I would ask you:

1. Is this a safe approach?
2. Is the server protected by wordpress or can I create a server middleware?
3. Can any stranger access to my app creating a localstorage with the same name?

Any answer or advice are appreciated.

**middleware/auth.global.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    // isAuthenticated() is an example method verifying if an user is authenticated
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {

        const useStateLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userAuthentication'));

        if (!useStateLocalStorage) {
            if (from.path === '/login') {
                return abortNavigation()
            }

            if (to.path !== '/login') {
                return navigateTo('/login')
            }
        }

        if (useStateLocalStorage) {
            if (to.path === '/login') {
                return abortNavigation()
            }
        }

    }
})
```

**/login.vue**

```
import { useUserStore } from "~/store/userAuth";

const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const signinForm = ref({ username: "", password: "" });
const userStore = useUserStore();

const signIn = async () => {

  const response = await $fetch(config.public.apiBaseUrl + '/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',
      {
        method: "post",
        body: {
          'username': signinForm.value.username,
          'password': signinForm.value.password
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {

        //SUCCESS
        //console.log('LOGIN SUCCESS', response);

        //SAVE USER DATA IN PINIA STORE
        userStore.IsAuth = true;
        userStore.token = response['data']['token'];
        userStore.username = response['data']['displayName'];
        userStore.email = response['data']['email'];
        userStore.firstName = response['data']['firstName'];
        userStore.lastName = response['data']['lastName'];

        //DEBUG

        console.log(userStore.IsAuth)
        console.log(userStore.token)
        console.log(userStore.username)
        console.log(userStore.email)
        console.log(userStore.firstName)
        console.log(userStore.lastName)

        //NAVIGATE TO HOME
        navigateTo('/')

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('LOGIN ERROR', error)
      });

  //console.log(response)
  signinForm.value = {username: "", password: ""};

}

userStore.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  localStorage.setItem('userAuthentication', JSON.stringify(state))
})
```

**store/userAuth.js**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            token: null,
            username: null,
            email: null,
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null,
            IsAuth: false
        }
    },
    persist: true,
    actions: {
        userUpdate(payload) {
            //localStorage.setItem('user-auth', payload)
            this.user = payload;
            this.IsAuth = payload;
        },
        tokenUpdate(payload) {
            //localStorage.setItem('user-auth', payload)
            this.token = payload;
        },
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with wordpress backend but I'd suggest generally avoid putting sensitive user data in localstorage as it's exposed to 3rd party scripts.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's not a good idea to put sensitive data in localstorage as it can be accessible any anyone